# Is there a simpler way to convert a external JSON object to a JS object?

Tags: javascript, json, web

```
var twitchProfile = {};
request("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/magnaboyy.json?client_id=8gkbch3ffqj35c1ccx088b9j6leifs8", function (error, response, body) {
const TwitchURL = body;
var jsonContent = JSON.parse(TwitchURL);
twitchProfile.display_name = (jsonContent.display_name);
twitchProfile.id = (jsonContent.id);
twitchProfile.name = (jsonContent.name);
twitchProfile.created_at = (jsonContent.created_at);
twitchProfile.logo = (jsonContent.logo);
console.log(twitchProfile);
```

In my code, I am grabbing the HTML body of the page (which is the json object) and then i am parsing each key in the object as a key in a JS object, considering I dont want to change anything in the names of the keys, or the content of the object, is there a way to convert the entire object over in one go, instead of all the components of it at a time? If not, am I doing it in a good way?

Comment: __"parsing each key in the object"__ ? No you are not! You are just parsing the `JSON` once...

Comment: Why not just assign `twitchProfile` to `jsonContent`?

Comment: What is the difference between twitchProfile & jsonContent?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just assign parsed object to your variable:

```
var twitchProfile = {};
request("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/magnaboyy.json?client_id=8gkbch3ffqj35c1ccx088b9j6leifs8", function (error, response, body) {
    const TwitchURL = body;
    var twitchProfile = JSON.parse(TwitchURL);
    console.log(twitchProfile);
}
```

Also if your 'TwitchProfile' already has some properties you have to merge objects. Method for merging described here: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: thank you, this makes sense, ive spent over an hour trying to further debug my code to work in async but its not working: https://jsfiddle.net/kecqpn48/ The request is inside the try, but ive tried moving it outside, using r.get, using rp.get(request-promise) and have no idea whats causing it(ive tried LOTS of solutions).

Comment: @Magnaboy jsfiddle doesn't work cause of missing includes. Did you see examples of module **request**?  https://github.com/request/request

Comment: I was just using jsfiddle as a way to show you the code, I've seen examples yes

Comment: it gives the second message in the code 'ERROR', do you have experience working with async javascript? the issue is with improper async syntax/formatting i think.

Comment: The code example is ok. But I saw that you're using await in jsfiddle. Please launch code without await first to see that response and parse is ok

Answer (score 1):

If you have different objects but need merge them together, in example:

```
var a = {
 x:0,
 y:1,
 z:2
}

var fromJSON = {
 x:11,
 y:12,
}
```

you can use [es6](/questions/tagged/es6)  [Object.Assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
var a = {
 x:0,
 y:1,
 z:2
}

var fromJSON = {
 x:11,
 y:12,
}

var assigned = Object.Assign(a,fromJSON);
console.log(assigned);

// assigned = {
//  x:11,
//  y:12,
//  z:2
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the only thing you could do to make it more readable is to use a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function).

See following example please:

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "name" : "Alessandro",
  "surname" : "Test",
  "age" : 34
};

function Person(json){
  this.name = json.name;
  this.surname = json.surname;
  this.age = json.age;
}

var person1 = new Person(jsonObj);

console.log("Hi " + person1.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ways to achieve this :**

**1.** You can create `deep copy` of the `source object` into the `destination(new) object` using **[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** and **[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** methods of JavaScript.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "display_name" : "alpha",
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "xyz",
  "logo" : "blablabla"
};

var twitchProfile = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));

console.log(twitchProfile);
```

**2.** Using **`ES6`** Spread operator and Destructing Assignment.

```
const jsonObj = {
  "display_name" : "alpha",
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "xyz",
  "logo" : "blablabla"
};
const {...twitchProfile} = jsonObj;
console.log(twitchProfile);
```

**3.** `Iterate` the source object using [**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop and `assign` the properties into `destination(new)` object.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  "display_name" : "alpha",
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "xyz",
  "logo" : "blablabla"
};

var twitchProfile = {};

for (var i in jsonObj) {
  twitchProfile[i] = jsonObj[i];
}

console.log(twitchProfile);
```